# Input Tags/Elements in AMP-html

Tags: html, input, amp-html

we are implementing our current [site](http://articles.mercola.com/sites/articles/archive/2099/12/31/alzheimers-disease-early-detection.aspx) in `AMP version` and i am new to this. I have below queries regarding `AMP` -

1. How to get user `input` from user in `AMP-HTML`.
2. In the above mentioned site [`desktop version`] we have `comment section` at the bottom of the page. We need to implement the same functionality in AMP.
3. Are there any `websites` which are build and developed in `AMP`? If yes, i need links to check.

Any suggestion and ideas related to above queries would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is still under experimental.
See: https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/a2477e1790d604dbc01997b6e0a9fe42ac6fa799/extensions/amp-form/amp-form.md